# отключить логирование переменных окружения в консоли

Tags: linux, node.js, node-modules

разрабатываю для себя сервер на Express.
захотелось добавить переменные окружения для удобства. добавил файл `.env` и записал туда переменные. но Node этот файл, как я вычитал, не видит и предложили установить `dotenv` пакет, чтобы переменные попали в `process.env`. установил, всё работает отлично, вот только каждый раз при перезапуске сервера в консоле выдает ВСЕ переменные из компа (не знаю как и не знаю зачем). это на работу никак не влияет, но жутко бесит, так как список переменных огромен. как это убрать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
еще уточню, что даже после удаления файла `.env` и пакета `dotenv`, всё так и осталось, до сих пор этот мусор в консоли остался.

Comment: умоляю, помогите..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
имя_комманды параметры 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

Как-то, примерно так.

Comment: извини, бро.
я нашел ошибку, и ошибка была в моей голове) просто запускал всё с Докера, а там не было обновленной конфигурации.
но всё равно низкий поклон за внимание и любви тебе :3